# How to type in a field and click a button on a site that I navigated to

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I was able to navigate to my desired site using the following code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com/");
```

How can I **provide an input from a variable** that I declared in CodeBehind? After that, I am planning to **click the button** and then further use the data.

Basically, my problem is about c**ontrolling the elements that are found in the site** that I navigated to using C#.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this a web based application or a widnows application?

Comment: you can use [selenium](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/) that is WebDriver in simple and easy language

Comment: Web-based since I'm using ASP.NET Web Forms for rapid development. @un-lucky

Answer (score 0):

Use Selenium. You can download the NuGet package from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver). Below is some code which goes to gmail and then finds the email textbox and types some text into in. It then presses a button.

```
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1");
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("Email")).SendKeys("myEmail"); // Type email
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("next")).Click(); // Click the button
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("Passwd")).SendKeys("myPass");
```

Also download the chromedriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and put the `.exe` file in your bin folder. Selenium will pick it from there and use it. You can use any web driver.

**EDIT**

To open a new tab:

```
IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
```

Comment: My current code is also using BackgroundWorker. Should I abandon it and directly use Selenium? My goal for this app is for the user to be able to be more productive after clicking a button that would run the task. It is some kind of automation that it saves the user some time. @CodingYoshi

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan I am not sure what your background worker is doing. Start without the background worker and get it working, then if you need the background worker add it. But first get it going without that.

Comment: Is it possible for Selenium to just open a new tab then navigate instead of opening a new browser? The site that I am planning to navigate to promotes single sign-on since it is for a company.

Comment: Yes see my edit please and also see the Selenium help online because there are plenty tutorials. Hope my answer helps.